# Handling screens of the Android devices having higher resolutions, like Samsung Tab

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I developed a mobile application with the min SDK version being 1.6. After referring to [an article regarding supporting multiple screen resolutions](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), I found out that I can use the `android:xlargeScreens="true"` for higher resolution screens in mobile devices like Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Will the images kept in the `drawable-xhdpi` folder be automatically referenced if I have the entry `android:xlargeScreens="true"` in the Android `Manifest` file?

Samsung Galaxy Tab is having screen resolution 600 × 1024 pixels. 
I can create images with respect to Samsung Tab’s screen dimensions. Even larger screen resolution Android devices come to the market, how to handle that?

Is there any other way to handle supporting multiple screen resolutions in a generic manner?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `drawable-` folders is the preferred way of handling multiple screen **densities**. The framework will automatically pull resources from the correct `drawable-` folder based on the screen density of the device. If you don't have drawables for that density, it will automatically scale them to match.

Check out [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details.

As far as supporting multiple **screen resolutions**, which are unrelated to **screen densities**, you just have to be flexible with your graphics. I think that a device maker can come out with a 601 x 1025 resolution screen if they want to. Try testing them out with the AVD if you are unsure about how your code responds. In any case, there's no way to predict the precise resolution your app will be running at.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the default resources (those without any specification) will be loaded, on xhdpi devices, the Android will first search on res/*-xhdpi to load resources, but will rely on default if there's any,

Note: If the only resource you have is specified to xlarge screens but you are trying to display it on a large screen you are going to get a ResourceNotFoundException.